# Scrapy hanging with any more than five spiders running

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to run multiple scrapy spiders at once, each from the command line. For example: command

```
>> python run_scrapy_spider_1.py
>> python run_scrapy_spider_2.py
```

However, once I already have 5 spiders running (all on different domains), the next one I try to run hangs with the message:

> INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6028

I don't think its an issue with the 6th site I am trying to run (it works fine when less than 5 spiders are running), but instead the fact that 5 spiders are already running.

Here is my very log output long incase it helps, any ideas how I can get more than 5 spiders running at once?

```
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 33, in emit
    payload = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 833, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 542, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 386, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'request_id'
Call stack:
  File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 16, in <module>
    SpiderTasks.run_spider_for_alexa_site_id(alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/code/green_brick_two/pricecomparison_project/pricecomparison/scripts/spider_scripts/spider_tasks.py", line 18, in run_spider_for_alexa_site_id
    process.crawl(MySpider, alexa_site_id=alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 69, in __init__
    self.spidermw = SpiderMiddlewareManager.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 48, in from_settings
    extra={'crawler': crawler})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1301, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1437, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1447, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/logging.py", line 47, in sentry_patched_callhandlers
    return old_callhandlers(self, record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 858, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 38, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: 'Enabled %(componentname)ss:\n%(enabledlist)s'
Arguments: {'componentname': 'spider middleware', 'enabledlist': "['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',\n 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',\n 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',\n 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',\n 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']"}
2019-03-03 22:34:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 33, in emit
    payload = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 833, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 542, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 386, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'request_id'
Call stack:
  File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 16, in <module>
    SpiderTasks.run_spider_for_alexa_site_id(alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/code/green_brick_two/pricecomparison_project/pricecomparison/scripts/spider_scripts/spider_tasks.py", line 18, in run_spider_for_alexa_site_id
    process.crawl(MySpider, alexa_site_id=alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 80, in crawl
    self.engine = self._create_engine()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 105, in _create_engine
    return ExecutionEngine(self, lambda _: self.stop())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.scraper = Scraper(crawler)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 71, in __init__
    self.itemproc = itemproc_cls.from_crawler(crawler)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 53, in from_crawler
    return cls.from_settings(crawler.settings, crawler)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/middleware.py", line 48, in from_settings
    extra={'crawler': crawler})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1301, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1437, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1447, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/logging.py", line 47, in sentry_patched_callhandlers
    return old_callhandlers(self, record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 858, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 38, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: 'Enabled %(componentname)ss:\n%(enabledlist)s'
Arguments: {'componentname': 'item pipeline', 'enabledlist': '[]'}
2019-03-03 22:34:30 [scrapy.middleware] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 33, in emit
    payload = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 833, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 542, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 386, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'request_id'
Call stack:
  File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 16, in <module>
    SpiderTasks.run_spider_for_alexa_site_id(alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/code/green_brick_two/pricecomparison_project/pricecomparison/scripts/spider_scripts/spider_tasks.py", line 18, in run_spider_for_alexa_site_id
    process.crawl(MySpider, alexa_site_id=alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 82, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 256, in open_spider
    logger.info("Spider opened", extra={'spider': spider})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1301, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1437, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1447, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/logging.py", line 47, in sentry_patched_callhandlers
    return old_callhandlers(self, record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 858, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 38, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: 'Spider opened'
Arguments: ()
2019-03-03 22:34:30 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider opened
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 33, in emit
    payload = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 833, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 542, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 386, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'request_id'
Call stack:
  File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 16, in <module>
    SpiderTasks.run_spider_for_alexa_site_id(alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/code/green_brick_two/pricecomparison_project/pricecomparison/scripts/spider_scripts/spider_tasks.py", line 18, in run_spider_for_alexa_site_id
    process.crawl(MySpider, alexa_site_id=alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 82, in crawl
    yield self.engine.open_spider(self.spider, start_requests)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 266, in open_spider
    yield self.signals.send_catch_log_deferred(signals.spider_opened, spider=spider)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/signalmanager.py", line 61, in send_catch_log_deferred
    return _signal.send_catch_log_deferred(signal, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 65, in send_catch_log_deferred
    *arguments, **named)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/logstats.py", line 35, in spider_opened
    self.task.start(self.interval)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/task.py", line 194, in start
    self()
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/task.py", line 239, in __call__
    d = defer.maybeDeferred(self.f, *self.a, **self.kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/logstats.py", line 48, in log
    logger.info(msg, log_args, extra={'spider': spider})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1301, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1437, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1447, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/logging.py", line 47, in sentry_patched_callhandlers
    return old_callhandlers(self, record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 858, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 38, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: 'Crawled %(pages)d pages (at %(pagerate)d pages/min), scraped %(items)d items (at %(itemrate)d items/min)'
Arguments: {'pages': 0, 'pagerate': 0.0, 'items': 0, 'itemrate': 0.0}
2019-03-03 22:34:30 [scrapy.extensions.logstats] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 33, in emit
    payload = self.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 833, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 573, in format
    s = self.formatMessage(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 542, in formatMessage
    return self._style.format(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 386, in format
    return self._fmt % record.__dict__
KeyError: 'request_id'
Call stack:
  File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 16, in <module>
    SpiderTasks.run_spider_for_alexa_site_id(alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/code/green_brick_two/pricecomparison_project/pricecomparison/scripts/spider_scripts/spider_tasks.py", line 18, in run_spider_for_alexa_site_id
    process.crawl(MySpider, alexa_site_id=alexa_site_id)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 172, in crawl
    return self._crawl(crawler, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 176, in _crawl
    d = crawler.crawl(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 83, in crawl
    yield defer.maybeDeferred(self.engine.start)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1532, in unwindGenerator
    return _inlineCallbacks(None, gen, Deferred())
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 1386, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = g.send(result)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 78, in start
    yield self.signals.send_catch_log_deferred(signal=signals.engine_started)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/signalmanager.py", line 61, in send_catch_log_deferred
    return _signal.send_catch_log_deferred(signal, **kwargs)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/utils/signal.py", line 65, in send_catch_log_deferred
    *arguments, **named)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/Twisted-18.4.0-py3.6-linux-x86_64.egg/twisted/internet/defer.py", line 150, in maybeDeferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pydispatch/robustapply.py", line 55, in robustApply
    return receiver(*arguments, **named)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scrapy/extensions/telnet.py", line 74, in start_listening
    extra={'crawler': self.crawler})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1301, in info
    self._log(INFO, msg, args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1437, in _log
    self.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1447, in handle
    self.callHandlers(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sentry_sdk/integrations/logging.py", line 47, in sentry_patched_callhandlers
    return old_callhandlers(self, record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 1509, in callHandlers
    hdlr.handle(record)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/logging/__init__.py", line 858, in handle
    self.emit(record)
  File "/home/ec2-user/MYVENV/lib/python3.6/site-packages/loggly/handlers.py", line 38, in emit
    self.handleError(record)
Message: 'Telnet console listening on %(host)s:%(port)d'
Arguments: {'host': '127.0.0.1', 'port': 6028}
2019-03-03 22:34:30 [scrapy.extensions.telnet] INFO: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6028
```

Comment: I don't see any error in log other than the `request_id`. Please check your code `File "run_spider_alexa_id.py", line 16`.

Comment: Do you get the same issue when you run multiple spiders in the way suggested in the documentation? See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#running-multiple-spiders-in-the-same-process